# Mapreduce give error Conversion string date

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In mapreduce, Reducer class in

```
public static class Reduce1 extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

     public void reduce(input,input,output,output) throws IOException  {
    String fromdate="2014-03-19 20:20:20";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate=sdf.parse(fromdate);
    }
}
```

It gives follwing error at compile time

> unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown

Any one knows solution and why this error is coming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ParseException` is a checked exception so you need to catch or throw it as indicated by the error message...

Answer (score 0):

Your code can throw ParseException (for example, if you have bad format).

And you have to throws it together with IOException or you can use try-catch to manually do something with it inside the method.

Comment: Already i have tried throwing ParseException  to redcuer method but it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

What @libik said is correct for a general answer. In your specific case, the interface for [Reducer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html#reduce%28K2,%20java.util.Iterator,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter%29) specifies the signature for the `reduce` method. You may not modify this signature in order to conform to the interface. This question is not actually related to mapreduce or Hadoop specifically, but rather it is more a basic Java question. So you may not throw `ParseException` from your `reduce` function because your exception clause does not allow that. So you have two choices, you can catch the `ParseException` and either swallow it or log it, or you can rethrow the exception wrapping it in an `IOException` or an unchecked `RuntimeException`.

```
try {
    String fromdate = "2014-03-19 20:20:20";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = sdf.parse(fromdate);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    throw new IOException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import and throw ParseException. And i think its better to initialize Date and SimpleDateFormat outside reduce method to save space :)

```
import java.text.ParseException;

public static class Reduce1 extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private Date startDate;
    public void reduce(<...>) throws IOException, ParseException  {
         String fromdate="2014-03-19 20:20:20";
         startDate=sdf.parse(fromdate);
    }
}
```